# Nav text going over header container in html

Tags: html, css, header, nav

I'm new to HTML and CSS in general. I'm trying to include nav links inside my header container, but instead, the text rolls over.

[CSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SK93m.png)

[HTML](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3yorp.png)

[Output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Km7vY.png)

The text is supposed to be inside the darker blue. If I edit the CSS and erase the line-height of 400% for header container it'll do the job, but I need that attribute. Thank you in advance.

Comment: prefer using a https://plnkr.co/ or a https://jsfiddle.net/ (or similar) instead of printscreens. It will be easier for us to debug and help you.

Comment: What are you using the line-height property for? Plus, you have a 1000 width in the nav without any unit.

Comment: Ill add the jsfiddle.net now, thanks for the tip. The line-height property is a requirement of the assignment. I'm guessing it'll eventually be a tool bar of that size.     https://jsfiddle.net/reinaldoVillasmil/ho3yz9xm/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add one of these to nav:

```
display: inline-block;
display: inline-flex;
or
display: inline-table;
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you